# parse.com PFQueryTableViewController is returning the same object multiple times

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to use `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object` to customize the display of `PFObject` data in a `PFQueryTableViewController`. So I construct my `PFQuery` object in `(PFQuery *)queryForTable` in my `PFQueryTableViewController` `delegate` that is supposed to obtain the multiple objects in an `NSArray`.

I thought that parse.com is supposed to then send/call `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object` once for each of the objects returned. However, I find that it keeps returning the *same* object multiple times.

Thus, for example, instead of 3 different objects for the 3 times `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object` is called, I get the same object. But it is not a problem with the data or the query, because at the end of `(PFQuery *)queryForTable` , just before

```
return query;
```

I tried

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *resultsNow,NSError *error) {NSLog(@"We have the following: %@", resultsNow);}];
 sleep(5);
```

and this shows the 3 objects obtained correctly. How is it that the exact *same* query when handled by `PFQueryTableViewController` calling `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object` 3 times, instead of sending the 3 objects one by one, it sends the first one 3 times?

In response to Wain's questions, I added some answers in the comments, but also the following seems relevant:

```
- (PFObject *)objectAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// overridden, since we want to implement sections
if (indexPath.section < self.objects.count) {
    return [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}

return nil;
}
```

Comment: What index paths are sent? What is provided to `objectsDidLoad:` / available in `objects`?

Comment: Thanks, Wain, for the good question. At first glance, it appears that objectsDidLoad: is just calling super and stuff like         `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;` and `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;` that shouldn't make a difference, but I'll explore that more.

Comment: As for the index paths, they are (in order, 1st, 2nd and 3rd time), `<NSIndexPath 0x1e86b5e0> 2 indexes [0, 0]`, `<NSIndexPath 0x1e84db30> 2 indexes [1, 0]` and `<NSIndexPath 0x1d5ce8f0> 2 indexes [0, 0]`

Comment: I mean you can log what gets received in `objectsDidLoad:` before the cells are updated.

Comment: Thanks Wain, really appreciate it! Sorry I have to go now, will take a look and update this another time with your suggestion. thanks again

Comment: Wain, logged and confirmed that the correct 3 objects are loaded in objectsDidLoad:, so the problem is later. It seems weird, but somehow, objectAtIndex:indexPath was not called! Hence my custom mapping was ignored, hence the weird behavior of `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object`

Comment: In case it may help anybody reading this in future, I found the problem (see my answer below), and it appears that the anypic example code may be using a method name of a PFQueryTableViewController method that has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Wain's question, I logged objectsDidLoad: and found that the correct 3 objects were loading, so it had to be a matter of the PFQueryTableViewController just not loading them in the right sequence in `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object`.

In particular, the mapping was supposed to be in `-(PFObject *)objectAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` as indicated in my question. But upon looking at the documentation for the Nth time, I suddenly noticed that the method name should actually be `-(PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. No wonder it wasn't being called, and my mapping was coming into effect, and hence the wrong object was being passed to `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object`. When I changed it to `-(PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, the problem went away!

How could I have got the wrong method name? I found that I had copied that mapping example from the anypic code, so I'm guessing that parse.com changed the method name sometime after anypic was written? Can anyone verify that? I'm using parse framework 1.2.14

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and what I did was:

1 -  Instead of using `PFQueryTableViewController` just use regular `UITableViewController`.

2 - Change the method `queryForTable:`to `(void)`.

`- (void)queryForTable {`

3 - Delete `PFQueryTableView`methods and implement `DataSource`methods.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
    }
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    }
```

Call `[self queryForTable]` in `viewDidLoad` after declaring it in .h file.

If you don't use block, you just create `NSArray` `property` and populate on `queryForTable`:

`self.yourarray = [query findobjects];`

If you use block, just make sure you populate `NSArray`inside block and reload tableview.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        // There was an error, do something with it.
    }
    else {
        self.yourArray = objects;
    }
    // Reload your tableView Data
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }); 
}];
```

This is how I got it working. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, but I would prefer to be able to get PFQueryTableViewController to work if possible, since it comes with some other conveniences.